# What's a good replacement for a D-Link DNS-320 ShareCenter?

Tags: wifi, hard-disk

- The D-Link product is no longer manufactured.
- I'm aware of software products such as [NAS4Free](http://www.nas4free.org/); I'd rather have a complete solution that doesn't involve acquiring more than one product.
- Raid 1; ability to work with Boxee Box; 2, preferably 3 TBytes per spindle.
- You'd be right if you've guessed that I pinch pennies.
- I've tried searching using terms including **sharecenter comparison** and **sharecenter alternative**.

Even if you can help me by suggesting other search terms I'd appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a preference for Synology.  Based on the D-Link specs you provided, either the "J Series" or the "Value Series" would be a good match.  Take a look at the [Synology site](https://www.synology.com/en-us/products?bays=bays_2) for more details

Pretty much the features/specs are the same - especially when it comes to the software and firmware.  The only notable differences would be in the hardware specs.

I have an older model 212j that works flawlessly.  I have upgraded it to new versions of the OS with zero issues and is fully compatible with my setup.  I hang 3 USB drives off of it for backup and a USB flash disk for storage of my music.

What's nice here too is that you can get it "[diskless](https://goo.gl/pR0YDR)" meaning the bays are empty.  This is how I bought mine (for under $200) at the time and put in two [WD Red 3TB NAS](https://goo.gl/4nk1Ry) drives cheaper than I could have bought it pre-populated.